# unable to get the data from Heroku server to ios

Tags: javascript, ios, heroku, parse-platform

I have javascript based application and I wanted created app for Android and IOS so I used phoneGap and converted to android and successfully converted to IOS .I am using back end as parse(Parse is closing) so I migrated from parse to Heroku and it is working perfectly for Android and for webApplication but it is not working in IOS I am unable to get the the data from heroku in IOS.This is how I am initilizing

```js
var config = {
  // Defaults
  IS_NODE: typeof process !== 'undefined' && !!process.versions && !!process.versions.node,
  REQUEST_ATTEMPT_LIMIT: 5,
  SERVER_URL: 'http://XXX.herokuapp.com/parse',
  VERSION: 'js' + '1.6.14',
  APPLICATION_ID: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  JAVASCRIPT_KEY: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
  MASTER_KEY: 'XXXXXXXX',
  USE_MASTER_KEY: true,
  PERFORM_USER_REWRITE: true,
  FORCE_REVOCABLE_SESSION: false
};
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should add `NSAppTransportSecurity` key to your info.plist file.
The iOS app doesn't response to `http` request unless you set `NSAppTransportSecurity`'s sub key `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads` to `YES`.
For more infomation, you can see [this](https://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/).

Comment: I added NSAppTransportSecurity into Plist.Still I am not getting.